# Is it required to have .Net framework installed to run or deploy asp.net core 3.1 application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to deploy the web api developed using asp.net core in the PLESK cloud but i am getting an error message during the deployment saying "Could not mark the folder as an application on the destination server. This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials that you are using"

I have given full access rights the user. Please help.

Is it required to have .Net framework installed to run or deploy asp.net core 3.1 application?

Comment: No its not required. And for deployemnt you only need .NET Core Hosting Bundle...By the way does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/18452265/6527049

Comment: @so have you solved your issue?

Comment: thank you Vivek nuna it is clear for core deployment. I could not relate the error i am facing with the link you have provided. i don't have an option to execute commands. I am trying to deploy using visual studio web deploy to the PLESK server.

Comment: Not yet. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Check you checked the permissions and all?

Comment: @SomasundaramR If you are able to login to the server, you can install .net core directly to the server. As I know, Plesk doesn't officially support .net core since I'm Plesk USER here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of now PLESK is not supporting for .net core 3.1

For more information:

https://in.godaddy.com/community/Plesk-Hosting/Is-ASP-Net-core-3-1-LTS-is-installed-on-Plesk-panel/m-p/155550#M1042